# What do the shops in Join Avenue sell at different ranks?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I've started leveling up my Join Avenue in Pokemon Black 2, and I'm not sure what the various shops will be selling. What are the different item shops and what do they sell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Raffle Shop** - Provides a possibility to win items such as a Master Ball
  [image]
- **Beauty Salon** - Sells services that increase the Happiness of your Pokémon
  [image]
- **Dojo** - Increases the level and stats of your Pokémon
  [image]
- **Market** - Sells sets of various items such as MooMoo Milk, Potions
  etc.
  [image]
  [image]
- **Florist** - Sells sets of various Berries 
  [image]
- **Antique Shop** - Sells a random selection of items including PokéBalls, Evolution Stones etc.
  [image]
- **Café** - Sells selection of food which increase Pokémon's stats and
  level 
  [image]
- **Nursery** - The nursery is a shop that improves the possibility for Egg Hatching. The nursery does not appear until you have reached Level 15 in Join Avenue rank and beaten the Elite Four. Unlike the others, they don't have varying items based upon games. You can receive multiple items per day unlike most making it a very useful feature
  [image]

Source: [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/black2white2/joinavenue.shtml)